How to properly create "messages" in JSON for OpenAI API in QT
The "messages" in OpenAI Chat completion requires it to have a format (order does not matter) as such
{ "messages" : [{"role": "user", "content": "Hello"}],
"model" : "gpt-3.5-turbo"
}
My challenge is how to properly create them using QJsonObject, QJsonArray in QT. The "brute force" by forcing putting QString with an escape "" in front of appropriate " works but it is ugly and hard to extend (after all the text part of Chat is dynamic).
Here is the code snippet. Test1 fails and Test2 (Brute force succeeds). In between the 2 tests, I have tried numerous QJSonObject, QJsonArrays combinations but to no avail. There has to be an elegant solution to this. Appreciate for your help.
void MainWindow::test6()
{
    QString str1 = "[{\"role\": \"user\", \"content\": \"Hello\"}]";

    /*
     * First Test
     */
    QJsonObject obj;
    obj["model"] = "gpt-3.5-turbo";
    obj["messages"] = str1;

    QJsonDocument doc(obj);
    QByteArray postData;
    postData = doc.toJson();
    qDebug().noquote() << postData;
    /*
     * Result is wrong - has escape \" instead of "
     * inside :

    {
       "messages": "[{\"role\": \"user\", \"content\": \"Hello\"}]",
       "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo"
    }

    */

    /*
     * Test2
     */
    QString str2 =   "{ \"messages\" : [{\"role\": \"user\", \"content\": \"Hello\"}], 
    \"model\" : \"gpt-3.5-turbo\"}";
    postData = str2.toUtf8();
    qDebug().noquote() << postData;

    /*
     * Result is correct

    { "messages" : [{"role": "user", "content": "Hello"}], "model" : "gpt-3.5-turbo"}

    */

}
By the way, I do know about qDebug().noquote() but this is not about display. This is about how to put into QByteArray a string which does not contain escape . Only without that when set via QNetWorkAccessManager post will work with OpenAI API
Thanks
